# R: Express the residuals of a linear model in percentages

Tags: r, regression, linear

I'm using `rlm()` method in R. My equation is y ~ x

The result should be `y = x + error`. How do I get this error from my results? Is this the Standard Error or the Residual standard error?

And how do I convert it in percentage?

Thank you in advance!

My results are shown below.

```
Call: rlm(formula = (B4FPS) ~ QPB4)
Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-10.8617  -3.7255  -0.6841   3.5321  15.3887 

Coefficients:
            Value   Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  0.7982  1.6530     0.4829
QPB4         1.7062  0.0619    27.5548

Residual standard error: 5.524 on 187 degrees of freedom
```

Comment: Cross-post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35866606/1412059

Comment: You really need to explain why you want to get "the error" and transform it into a percentage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `resid()` function to get your residuals (i.e. errors). You can also formulate the values in the percentage, although I doubt that this may not be that meaningful. In any case, the following should get you the error values in percentage:

```
library(MASS)
data <- data.frame(x=rnorm(200), y=rnorm(200)+5)
lm1 <- rlm(y~x, data=data)
#getting the residuals in percentage (y-yhat)/y
err_percent <- 100*(resid(lm1)/data$y)
head(err_percent)
        1          2          3          4          5          6 
 -1.445646 -44.408882 -15.993623   5.244996  -3.311191  24.453182
```

Keep in mind that some values will be negative because you are working with the residuals, and not the ***squared errors***.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So in case I want the average error I will get the `mean(err_percent)` right? Also, I'll use `err_percent <- 100*abs(resid(lm1)/data$y)`

Comment: It very much depends on what you want to do with the results. If you care about both direction and magnitude--like by how much the predicted value is bigger or smaller than the data--then you may want to stick with the current response. But if you only need the magnitude of the difference between actual value and predicted value, then you may go ahead and use the absolute value of the residual values. Either way you are at a decent starting point.